# Fail to set turtle's average heading with error message "mean expected input to be a list but got the number XXX instead"

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to ask turtles to turn toward to average leader's heading when they are find nearest leader, however when run the code, this error message pop-up "mean expected input to be a list but got the number XXX instead" and it's point to this code:

```
 [turn-towards average-heading-towards-leaders max-cohere-turn]
```

below is my complete code:

```
to go
 ask turtles [check]
 tick
end

to check
 if leader? 
  [let beings-seen patches in-cone leader-vision leader-vision-angle with [pcolor = red] 
    ifelse any? beings-seen 
     [let target one-of beings-seen
    face target ] 
    [flock]]
end

to flock
 let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ]
 if any?  nearby-leaders in-radius vision
 [turn-towards average-heading-towards-leaders max-cohere-turn]
end

to-report average-heading-towards-leaders  
 let nearby-leaders turtles with [leader? ]
 let x-component mean [sin heading] of one-of nearby-leaders
 let y-component mean [cos heading] of one-of nearby-leaders
 ifelse x-component = 0 and y-component = 0
  [ report heading ]
  [ report atan x-component y-component ]
end
```

can somebody point what wrong with my code. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with these two lines:

```
 let x-component mean [sin heading] of one-of nearby-leaders
 let y-component mean [cos heading] of one-of nearby-leaders
```

`[sin heading] of one-of nearby-leaders` reports the sine of the heading of one of the nearby leaders, which is a single number. `mean` expects a list. So you're trying to pass a number to something that expects a list.

To fix it, you can just get rid of the `mean`s in those lines.

Comment: Note that `dx` and `dy` are short for `sin heading` and `cos heading`, respectively.